# Using proxy to remove SSL overhead from client

Tags: ssl, proxy

I know many application uses reverse proxy to reduce SSL overhead from the application, where handshake and encryption/decryption are between the client and proxy, and the back-end app get the stripped data from proxy on HTTP or other protocol.

I heard it is possible to use same concept to reduce SSL overhead from the client, but couldn't find any reference or guide for such configuration. I'm fully aware it is insecure method.

Comment: what proxy do you want to use? 
What you are referring to is SSL termination and backend servers being on http instead on https. you can see multiple examples of SSL termination for nginx or haproxy online, you just put proxy_pass or server on http/port 80 instead of https/port 443 e.g https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-implement-ssl-termination-with-haproxy-on-ubuntu-14-04 or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-nginx-load-balancing-with-ssl-termination

Answer (score 0):

First, measure your actual performance. Insert some timers in the client to get some idea of what the user experience actually is. Premature optimization is problematic, you spend effort making compromises that may not be needed.

You do not need to abandon encryption to improve performance. Upgrading and optimizing a TLS stack can be a win. Try OCSP stapling, TLS 1.3 0-RTT, and HTTP/2. Read a summary of these at  https://istlsfastyet.com/  and run down [the checklist in the book *High Performance Browser Networking*](https://hpbn.co/transport-layer-security-tls/#optimizing-for-tls).